# When are ListBoxItems created for ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox that I bind to an ItemsSource, like this:

```
var foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo> { foo1, foo2, foo3 };
var listBox = new ListBox { ItemsSource = _foos };
```

Now I want to do some operations right away on the ListBoxItems that holds the items, but they don't seem to be created right away. Are they? Is there some event I can listen to in order to be notified, or am I simply trying to fetch the ListBoxItem's in an invalid way? I am doing it like this (and have verified that it works somewhere I know the ListBox is "ready"):

```
var lbi = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(foo1) as ListBoxItem;
```

Note that this is being done in a unit test, so I guess the ListBox is never rendered. Is that why the ListBoxItems aren't created? And can I manually trigger the creation of the ListBoxItems somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items-creation is done async and depending on the panel, it can happen that it is not created at all ([virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx)). The event your're looking for is [`ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.statuschanged(v=VS.100).aspx). Do a google-search for it on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search), you will find many examples. However directly searching and working with the items can get complex.

[Here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/) is a very good article that discusses the item-creation in detail. Look also for the [ancestor](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/)-article .

BTW:
I recommend you to look at the MVVM-pattern. While there is a small bit of time you loose learning it (not comparable to the time learnding WPF), it will save you a lot of time. [Here](http://hugeonion.com/2009/03/08/wpf-mvvm-video-by-jason-dolinger/) you find a link to a video from Jason Dolinger that gives you a great start-point.

**Update:**

As promised in the comment, here a function to search the visual tree (only usable when virtualization is off).

```
void FindChildFrameworkElementsOfType<T>(DependencyObject parent,IList<T> list) where T: FrameworkElement{             
    DependencyObject child; 
    for(int i=0;i< VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);i++){             
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i); 
        if (child is T) { 
            list.Add((T)child); 
        } 
        FindChildFrameworkElementsOfType<T>(child,list); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thx. Will look into the articles and try using the StatusChanged event. I am already using MVVM, and the video is indeed great. However, in this case I need to get down to the details for the unit tests of a custom control inheriting ListBox that I'm working on.

Comment: @stiank81: If your lists have few items, you can disable virtualizing with VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" on the ListBox. For small sets of data this would not be a problem. Depending on your unit test, you can disable the virtualization also only for the unit test.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do this only for the unit tests, but it doesn't seem like I can reach it from the code. It says that it is a private Property, but why can I reach it from xaml then? Any idea if I can trigger this from code somehow?

Comment: The article was really interesting! Thx! That explains alot, but still leaves me with problems.. Tried using the ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged event and waiting for it to execute before I continue, but it is never triggered in my unit tests. Any way I can trigger the generation manually?..

Comment: @stiank81: Try yourListBox.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing,false) or VirtualizingStackPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(yourListBox,false)

Comment: The second option works for deaktivating virtualization, but still no ListBoxItems, and still no StatusChanged triggered.. +1 btw..

Comment: Another possibility to get the Items is through the VisualTreeHelper. If virtualization is off, all items should be available and you can get them through it. I will extend my answer...

Comment: @stiank81: I have never done a unit test for WPF. Are you shure that all the rendering-stuff and item-creation is done within your test?

Comment: Well - it seems like it's not happening.. I am creating the WPF object in the STA thread, but that's all really. So I guess it's not being rendered, and that's why the containers are never created? Do you know if there is anything I can do to trigger the rendering or something like that?..

Comment: You can try to use RenderTargetBitmap to create an Image from your Visual, maybe this will trigger the creation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx